# In my app I am not receiving speed in location object in Moto G 3rd generation Android 6.0 mobile

Tags: android, google-play-services, motorola

In my app I am using FusedLocation.API for location updates, and I am using google play services-7.8.0.
In onLocationChange() method, in location object i am not getting speed in Moto G(3rd Gen) Android 6.0.
In all other mobiles I am able to receive speed.
I tried with google play service versions 8.4.0 and 9.0.2 but no luck!

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(0);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, mLocationListener);
```

Can anyone please tell what could be the problem for this issue and how to overcome this issue ?

**I am targeting for SDK 21 and also my compile SDK version is 21**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you get runtime permissions while compiling against 6.0?

Comment: I am targeting for SDK 21 and also my compile SDK version is 21 and I have declared all the required persmissions. Its working fine in all other devices except Moto G 3rd generation Android 6.0

Answer (score 1):

In marshmallow and higher location is considered a "Dangerous permission" Here's the article for google. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

there's several third party libraries to help manage permissions

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/235

also make sure your permissions are declared in your manifest.xml

Comment: I am targeting for SDK 21 and also my compile SDK version is 21 and I have declared all the required persmissions. Its working fine in all other devices except Moto G 3rd generation Android 6.0

Comment: under settings>apps>your app> permissions take a look there. that way we can see if this is a permissions issue at all.

Comment: My app has all the permissions 'ON', that are needed by app. Moreover it is working fine in other devices like Nexus 5 android 6.0, but it is only not working in Moto G 3rd Generation android 6.0 device.

Comment: my next question is it isolated to just the Motorola? I mean if you test on an marshmallow emulator does it work?

Comment: Yes, exactly this issue is only in Moto G Android 6.0

Comment: I encountered the same issue and it only happens on users with Moto G and Android 6.0.

Comment: @Lachezar To overcome the issue I used Android framework location manager for receiving location updates instead of FLP(Fused Location Provider) as I didn't find any other way to make it resolve.